# is it possible to send an ajax with arrays in them?

Tags: ajax

I always notice the json having object with key value pair.

```
 {"name": "Brett", "country": "Australia"}
```

But I have never seen this way with array in it:

```
{"name": "Brett", "country": "Australia", "Hobby":["soccer", "baseball"]}.
```

Is this even possible? If so how is this even getting stored in the backend.

Comment: Would you be using php ?

Comment: Not php. but wondering if it is possible? how does this form work from front end?

Comment: It is possible, I've added a solution using `php`.

Comment: What happened when you tested the second example?

Comment: According to json lint both of them works. since I have never seen this kind before working my way as to how it is sent from front end in arrays through a form?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is valid. check a json validation tool.
[jsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as `php` is concerned, I can simply pass an array via trivial methods.
Here's an example.

```
arrayName = [];
arrayName[0] = 'Stack';
arrayName[2] = 'Overflow';
arrayName[3] = 'Rocks';
//now I can easy send this array to via ajax.
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {info:info},
   url: "index.php",
   success: function(msg){
     //do something here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.. In the backend, you can map the Json to an object. If the backend is in Java, you can use Jackson.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Hope it helps..